# Forms authentication and authorization that uses custom database tables? Asp.net web forms(C#).

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Hi i am currently creating a web forms asp.net website, i am trying to  add forms authentication with the following code for the login page below but i am now unable to login. I have all the appropriate code in the HTML and the web.config file and i am not receiving any errors. I may be going about the authentication for web forms wrong, any help would be appreciated. Thank You

```
private bool ValidateUser(string Username, string Password)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new      SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd;
        string lookupPassword = null;

        // Check for invalid userName.
        // userName must not be null and must be between 1 and 15 characters.
        if ((null == Username) || (0 == Username.Length) || (Username.Length > 15))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("[ValidateUser] Input validation of userName failed.");
            return false;
        }

        // Check for invalid passWord.
        // passWord must not be null and must be between 1 and 25 characters.
        if ((null == Password) || (0 == Password.Length) || (Password.Length > 25))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("[ValidateUser] Input validation of passWord failed.");
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            // Consult with your SQL Server administrator for an appropriate connection
            // string to use to connect to your local SQL Server.

            conn.Open();

            // Create SqlCommand to select pwd field from users table given supplied userName.
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select password from customer where Username=@userName", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", TextBoxPassword.Text);
            cmd.Parameters["@userName"].Value = Username;

            // Execute command and fetch pwd field into lookupPassword string.
            lookupPassword = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            // Cleanup command and connection objects.
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Add error handling here for debugging.
            // This error message should not be sent back to the caller.
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("[ValidateUser] Exception " + ex.Message);
        }

        // If no password found, return false.
        if (null == lookupPassword)
        {
            // You could write failed login attempts here to event log for additional security.
            return false;
        }

        // Compare lookupPassword and input passWord, using a case-sensitive comparison.
        return (0 == string.Compare(lookupPassword, Password, false));

    }

    private void cmdLogin_ServerClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ValidateUser(TextBoxUserN.Text, TextBoxPassword.Text))
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(TextBoxUserN.Text,
                chkPersistCookie.Checked);
        else
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx", true);
    }
```

Comment: What does ValidateUser() return? What does it do next?

Comment: Please don't store passwords in plaintext. https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: @shawnt00 ValidateUser() doesnt return anything it is just being used to validat the user against the data them i am going to redirect the user to the homepage if they are valid.

Comment: And then it either returns true or false. I see you haven't been inside the debugger at all...

Comment: I apologies i am new to asp.net and just trying to make the website more secure

Comment: You might be new to ASP.NET, but I assume you are not new to asking questions.  Normally a question has a question mark, OK?  And you need to try to figure out the problem yourself and at the very least find out exactly where in the code the problem is.  No one is going to go through all of that code for you.  You must find where the problem is first.  Don't be so lazy and expect everyone else to do your job for you.

Comment: I wasn't being lazy and tried a number of different ways of creating authorization for the website and had done a lot of research with the majority being overkill and relating to asp.net mvc. The code i provided was my best attempt i will continue to try get it working. Its for a final year project so I'm not even sure if authorization is a priority thanks anyway.

Comment: try not to take offense to it @colliec, people here get can get uptight about how you ask questions, make sure you read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question is pretty broad, for best results try to really pinpoint your issue.

Comment: Thanks Dan, i will keep that in mind and try to improve my questions.

Comment: You should probably post the web.config as well.

Answer (score 1):

Click event's **access modifier** must be protected. Normally, VS throws Compilation Error when you browser the page.

```
protected void cmdLogin_ServerClick 
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to break your idea in pieces and implement them, it will make the debug much more easy.

Short for Text box is txt, ex: txtUserName or txtPassword, full list here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263493%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Here is how this should be done in my opinion:

1. Validate username and password length, let user know if they are invalid (by displaying a message in the page, for example using a label called lblMessage, not "redirect to login.aspx", user don't know wth happened, the best is to use validation controls but you can use whatever...)
2. If (1) is valid, then check if username + password are matched in database, let user know if they are invalid ((by displaying a message in the page...).
3. If (2) is valid, redirect to appropriate page.

Here the code (syntax was not checked)

```
    protected void cmdLogin_ServerClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    try {
        lblMessage.Text = "";

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxUserN.Text) || TextBoxUserN.Text.Length > 15) {
            lblMessage.Text = "Username is invalid!";
            return;
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxPassword.Text) || TextBoxPassword.Text.Length > 25) {
            lblMessage.Text = "Password is invalid!";
            return;
        }

        if (ValidateUser(TextBoxUserN.Text, TextBoxPassword.Text)) FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(TextBoxUserN.Text,
        chkPersistCookie.Checked);
        else lblMessage.Text = "Username and password combination is incorrect!";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        lblMessage.Text = "An error has occurred, please try again later!";
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("[ValidateUser] Exception " + ex.Message);
    }
}

private bool ValidateUser(string username, string password) {
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS)) {
        string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer WHERE UserName = @username AND password = @password COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS"; //password is case SeNsiTive
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
        con.Open();
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        //con.Close();
        if (i == 1) return true //Correct username + password                
        else return false; //Wrong username + password
    }
}
```